# Migrating from Python 2.5 to 2.7 with appengine and django non-rel

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, django-nonrel

I read the "what is a metaclass in Python" but am still confused over it.

I am new to python and have been thrown into upgrading it from 2.5 to 2.7.

I have the following:

```
class UsersDB(db.Model):
Email = db.EmailProperty(required=True,verbose_name='Email *')
Enable = db.BooleanProperty(default=True)
```

and

```
class UsersQuickAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
def is_user_exist(self, account):
    users_query = UsersDB.all().filter('Email =', account).fetch(1)
    if len(users_query) > 0:
        return True
    return False
class Meta:
    model = UsersDB
    exclude = ['Enable']
```

but when I try to execute it on the google site, I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
>       handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
>       handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
>     File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
>       obj = **import**(path[0])
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ldsdgidev/glen27.371429613087607751/LDSGH.py", line 8, in 
>       from core.decorators import permissionRequired
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ldsdgidev/glen27.371429613087607751/core/decorators.py", line 7, in 
>       from core.initialization import loginIf
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ldsdgidev/glen27.371429613087607751/core/initialization.py", line 6, in 
>       import photo_images
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ldsdgidev/glen27.371429613087607751/core/photo_images.py", line 1, in 
>       from core.db_models import ImagesDB
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ldsdgidev/glen27.371429613087607751/core/db_models.py", line 222, in 
>       class UsersQuickAddForm(forms.ModelForm):#only account, firstname and last name is required
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ldsdgidev/glen27.371429613087607751/django/forms/models.py", line 205, in **new**
>       opts.exclude, opts.widgets, formfield_callback)
>     File "/base/data/home/apps/s~ldsdgidev/glen27.371429613087607751/django/forms/models.py", line 145, in fields_for_model
>       opts = model._meta
>   AttributeError: type object 'UsersDB' has no attribute '_meta'

and I don't understand what I need to add to the UserDB class to get rid of the error.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't anything to do with Python versions, or metaclasses.

ModelForms only work with Django models. `db.Model` is the App Engine model class, not the Django one. You can't use a modelform with that class.

You mention django-nonrel in your question tags. That project allows you to use the Django models - subclasses of `models.Model` with the App Engine datastore. You probably want to do that.

Comment: Hmm, ok..  Maybe I am not reading things right, most of what I found has django non-rel stating that I can do as I did above as long as I have put the django non-rel package in my project so it defaults to those packages instead of picking up the appengine default django packages.

Comment: Not sure where you're looking. [Here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django-nonrel#md) for example is a blog on the GAE site itself, saying that you should use django's model class not the App Engine one.

Comment: I did see that, but that turns it into a pure django app and does not support the appengine database backend which I need to still  use with this application due to the extensive size of the existing data that is there.  The owner will not let me change the backend database.  I know I am not understanding something here and that's what is frustrating me.

Comment: Well, you do seem to be a bit confused. But this has nothing to do with what data store you're using, only the API you use to access it. The whole point of django-nonrel is to allow you to use Django's model class (and therefore modelforms) with the App Engine datastore.

Comment: Ok, I'll give that a try and see what happens, I will rate once I see if I understand.  Maybe even sooner.. Thanks.

Comment: Well I definitely got past that part and have accepted the answer, but am still having issues that are not part of this thread..